# how do you pkill a jar with sigterm

Tags: java, shell, unix, ubuntu, kill

i have a process like this:

```
actor    19130     1  0 16:13 pts/0    00:00:02 java -jar /home/opt/zimbraconnector/zimbraconnector.jar
```

i tried to kill it with a signal :

```
pkill -SIGTERM -f zimbraconnector.jar
```

but its not working. Any clue whats wrong here? Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The process is not `zimbraconnector.jar`, it's `java -jar /home/opt/zimbraconnector/zimbraconnector.jar`. You'll have to kill `java`

Comment: ^ What he said. Also, you can `kill` with the pid (`kill -15 19130` or something)

Comment: thanks guys, i dont want to kill java, because other processes are running and they need java. can i rewrite in a way that it would find out the pid and then kill it?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but `ps -x | grep zimbraconnector.jar` (should also work without the `-x` option) should give you the exact information for your jar. You may then extract the pid and kill it

Comment: @Ikthiander each application 'using Java' will have a unique Java process that you can kill. Its not an all or nothing deal.